# How to save CPU cycles in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, performance-testing

What are the ways to save CPU cycles in a Ruby web application? As my project is expanding, the average time for rendering, running methods, db queries is increasing. I consider average of 60ms as high. 
Any design guidelines to keep machine code tight and compact? Like - Being completely OO?
Using more variables and memory to avoid repeated iteration etc? Consolidating db queries?

Comment: if you want faster code try java or C++

Comment: Agreed.  Ruby seems pretty powerful and great for getting stuff running quickly, but not for getting stuff running *fast*.  It's one of the slowest languages out there.  But even sticking with Ruby, there are probably ways to speed things up a tad.

Comment: Those ways are dependent on the existing code, though.  Considering we don't have that to narrow down performance issues, it'd take whole books to cover possible optimizations.

Comment: I am still new to Ruby, and my project requires too much processing of that data. Both things make a long code which I think has room to be compacted.

Answer (score 3):

try to find out your bottlenecks before actually start tuning everything.

Are you sure the problem is in the CPU? could it be your storage system?, is it your methods? is it your DB? are you using idices in your db? are you using more indices that you need in your db?

Answer (score 3):

There is no all in one solution for your question.

You should run you application against a profiler, which will determine which point of your software eat the most resources. Optimize that part, and repeat the operation, until you're happy with the results.

There are plenty tools for measuring performance, ruby-prof, gperftools , and such stuff like newrelic, check out this keywords on google

Comment: If you are using the JRuby VM which you should most definitely look at then you can also try out JXInsight/Opus for JRuby http://www.jinspired.com/site/jxinsight-opus-for-jruby-edition-1-0

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html)? It's a very important tool for speeding up your web application and making it scale to high traffic, and in many cases it is orders of magnitude more efficient than regular code optimizations.

Comment: Caching should be the last thing AFTER profiling and optimisation. It is hard to maintain and debug. Remember the famous words that one of the hardest things in software development is cache invalidation.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the (correct) answers of profiling your code to find the parts that are actually slow, you could also look into alternate Ruby implementations that could be faster for your use case.

See:

- http://jruby.org/
- http://rubini.us/

for two alternatives that are reported to be faster than the standard 1.9 interpreter.